# What hypothesis testing to use for continuous to categorical variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binary-data, continuous-data

For example, I'd like to know **if a person's age (a continuous variable) is related to whether the person drinks (a categorical/binary variable of Y or N)**. What method should I use to know

1. If there's a significant relationship.
2. The strength of the association.
3. The direction of the association - whether younger people tend to drink, or the opposite.

Comment: I can think of many way, the easiest of which is just to run a t-test of age in the drinker and non-drinker group, so it will depend on what specific questions you have. Being completely literal with the three you posted, however, a t-test of the ages is completely reasonable.

Comment: I agree with @Dave, provided ages within the two groups are not far from normal.

Answer (score 1):

What to do here would depend also on sample size, you didn't tell us. If sample size is large enough, you can use logistic regression, possible with splining age. That would also allow for a more complicated (nonmonotone) relationship.  That is what is proposed at [T-tests, manova or logistic regression - how to compare two groups?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/t-tests-manova-or-logistic-regression-how-to-compare-two-groups), which have more details.

Another similar question is [Logistic regression or T test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159110/logistic-regression-or-t-test)

Comment: I think this is probably the best approach, with the implication that *Drinks* is the dependent variable.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the ages of $n_1=20$ randomly sampled subjects who drink are
$X_i \sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 40, \sigma=7),$ rounded to the next lower year. Independently, suppose ages of $n_2=25$ randomly sample subjects
who abstain are $Y_i \sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 30, \sigma=5),$ similarly rounded. Then your data might be similar to the fictitious data
sampled in R below:

```r
set.seed(2022)
x = floor(rnorm(20, 40, 7))
y = floor(rnorm(25, 30, 5))
```

Of course, in a real study, you would not know the population
mean and variances. But from the data you could find summary statistics as shown below. This gives the impression that drinkers
are often older than abstainers.

```r
summary(x);  length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  19.70   33.29   39.07   38.05   42.77   47.14 

[1] 20         # size of first sample
[1] 7.002077   # SD of first sample

summary(y)  length(y);  sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  22.21   28.26   30.59   30.15   33.25   36.06 
[1] 25
[1] 3.948933
```

Boxplots (x on bottom) of the two samples are as follows. There are not signs of severe skewness or of many outliers, so we believe
the data are roughly normal. It seems appropriate to do a Welch two-sample t test (which does not assume equal variances) to see if
the difference between $\bar X = 38.05$ and $\bar X = 30.15$ is
statistically significant at the 5% level.

```r
hdr="Ages of 20 drinkers and (top) 25 abstainers"
boxplot(x,y, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
```

[image]

A printout from `t.test` in R for these two samples is shown below.
The P-value $0.0001 < 0.05 = 5\%$ shows that the null hypothesis
is rejected.

```r
t.test(x, y)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 4.5042, df = 28.441, p-value = 0.0001042
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  4.309023 11.488299
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 38.05252  30.15386
```

Of course, your real data might show a difference in the other
direction of nor significant difference at all, but the procedures
would be the same for nearly-normal data.

A95% confidence interval for difference between the ages of drinkers and abstainers is given in the output above as $(4.3,\, 11.5).$

Answer (score 0):

Because the categorical variable has two categories, one could also just use correlation:  Pearson, Spearman, or Kendall.  This might be the most appropriate approach for "association" where the dependent and independent variables aren't specified.  The direction should be clear, and these methods report a measure of the strength of the association that people are fairly familiar with:  *r*, *rho*, or *tau*.

Comment: Readers should note that correlation between a binary variable and a numerical variable is sometimes called *point biserial correlation*.