Is logistic regression as reliable as traditional statistical tests to measure differences between groups?
I am working on an case-control analysis where I have to report whether or not these groups are actually comparable. I have performed different statistical tests on the independent variables of interest (e.g. age, sex, height, weight, pathologies each patient suffers, etc.). However, I am reconsidering using a logistic regression, in order to see if any of the variables can be meaningfully used to predict being in one group or the other.
My question is: Is logistic regression as reliable for this purpose as traditional methods (like using a t-test for one variable, a Mann-Whitney U for another, etc.)? Or are the potential problems (e.g. multicollinearity) limiting the capability this method has to measure statistically significant differences?

In short, yes. Pretty much all common statistical tests can be written as regression models. Multicollinearity doesn't really present a huge problem in terms of significance/confidence intervals; it can have an effect on the coefficient estimates, but that's not a huge issue if the research question is more along the lines 'is there an association?', rather than 'how big is the association?'. The main advantage of using a mutlivariable regression model in this context is the ability to adjust for covariates, which is generally useful.

Does this answer your question? Is logistic regression an alternative to t-test?

Or possibly https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159110 addresses your questions?  It shows that logistic regression is different, implying that before you can answer any questions about being more or less "reliable" you will have to decide what it is you are testing.

I'm not sure what your goal is, but I guess you'd like to show that the cases and the controls are comparable in age, height, sex etc. Let's look at only age. In logistic regression you would then use age as independent to predict Y (Y=0 for control, Y=1 for cases, say). If you would then find that there is no significant effect of age, you would call the two groups, cases and controls, "comparable in age". Ideally, the effect of age should be exactly zero, for such conclusion. So, you would have to choose a particular significance level for the effect of age first, like p > 0.1, to justify the conclusion that "age has no influence on group memberschip". Or should you choose p > 0.2 or p > 0.5? That's a problem.
But more difficult is this. Suppose the effect of age would be perfectly zero with p=1, could you then conclude that the cases and the controls are comparable w.r.t. age? I do not think so, because the distribution of age could be completely different for the two groups.  For example, say age runs from 1 to 100, one person per age year. There are 50 cases and 50 controls. For the cases, age runs from 26 to 75. For the controls age runs from 1 to 25, and from 76 to 100. Running the logistic regression would produce an age effect of zero, with p=1. Look at the simulation below:
x <- 1:100
y <- ifelse(x < 26 | x > 75, 0, 1)

m1 <- glm(y ~ x, family=binomial)
summary(m1)

With results:
glm(formula = y ~ age, family = binomial)

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  5.161e-16  4.030e-01       0        1
age         -8.461e-18  6.929e-03       0        1

The predicted values of this model are 0.5 for each age:
predp <- predict(m1, type="response")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + aes(age, predp) + geom_line()


The zero effect for age, does NOT mean that the controls and cases are comparable in age. In mean age they compare well, but not in variance or in distribution.
In the above example there is a nonlinear relation of course between age and group membership, which you may be able to detect with the logistic regression, but that will not be easy, in general. Which nonlinear relation should  you choose? Comparing the age distributions (e.g. histograms) of the two groups would be a much easier task.
