Logistic regression versus mean and variance, which estimate is more efficient and why?
Let
$$\begin{array}{}
Y_i & \sim& Bernoulli(0.5) \\
X_i|Y_i &\sim& N(\mu_{Y_i},\sigma^2)
\end{array}$$
In this case we can consider independent pairs of observations $X_i,Y_i$ following the model of a logistic regression where the $Y_i$ has a conditional Bernoulli distribution with
$$P(Y_i=1|X_i=x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(a+bx)}}$$
where $a = \frac{\mu_1^2-\mu_0^2}{2\sigma^2}$ and $b=\frac{\mu_0-\mu_1}{\sigma^2}$
So, we can estimate these parameters $a$ and $b$ in two different ways

Perform logistic regression.
Estimate $\mu_i$ and $\sigma$ directly with the assumed normal distribution, then compute to the parameters $a$ and $b$.

The two methods will not give the same result. Which method is most efficient (has the expected squared error)?

To clarify my question a bit further. It is also about understanding.
Here is a simulation that shows that the estimate of mean and variance results in smaller error. And it could answer the question.

But is it general?
And why wouldn't logistic regression perform the same?
What sort of information does the knowledge about the distribution of $X_i$ add and could this be incorporated into the logistic regression (e.g. by adding weights) to make it perform better?

set.seed(1)

sim = function(n, mu) {

  Y = rbinom(n,1,0.5)
  X = rnorm(n,Y*mu,1)

  mod = glm(Y ~ X, family = binomial)
  glm_est = mod$coefficients

  m = c(mean(X[Y==0]), mean(X[Y==1]))
  V = (sum((X-m[Y+1])^2)/(n-2))

  mm_est = c(-diff(m^2)/2/V,
             diff(m)/V)

  return(c(glm_est, mm_est))
}

mu = 1
z = replicate(10^3, sim(200, mu))

true_a = -mu^2/2
true_b = mu

### glm_errors
mean((z[1,]-true_a)^2) # 0.03592216
mean((z[2,]-true_b)^2) # 0.03245813

### gaussian_mm_errors
mean((z[3,]-true_a)^2) # 0.01323784
mean((z[4,]-true_b)^2) # 0.03075781


I would say that the sample mean and sample variance of the groups would be sufficient statistics, and should lead to a most efficient estimate. But I remember making once simulations of this situation and the logistic regression didn't do that bad at all (maybe even better, I don't remember). Possibly it might be due to biased estimates when we compute values like $\mu/\sigma$?

I expect that under the restricted assumptions of normality and equal variance the sample mean and SD will give rise to the most efficient estimates. Of course this completely breaks down with categorical X.

I think $\sigma$ should be squared in the expressions for $a$ and $b$.

Also, the two methods would also apply if $p\neq 1/2$, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/288290/77222 so you would perhaps not want to restrict the question to $p=1/2$ only?

@JarleTufto the $p=1/2$ restriction is not really that much important for the concept. My main reason for using a Bernoulli distribution for $Y_i$ was to make the observed pairs $X_i,Y_i$ independent (contrary to the case where I would have fixed number of classes $Y_i = 0$ and $Y_i = 1$).

Thinking about the situation where the two distributions are nearly completely seperated, it seems obvious that the logistic regression will perform badly, but the knowledge about the distribution of the classes still gives accurate information. I am still puzzled about how this can be formulated more theoretically.

If I take 1.05 times the Gaussian based estimate and subtract 0.05 times the logistic regression estimate, then I have a better estimate even though the bias is not changed a lot (it is not like a shrinkage or regularised estimate).

I notice that with a sample as small as this, MLE is biased, but using a Firth correction removes the bias and increases the precision in the estimate for b. Add method = brglm2::brglm_fit to implement this. This makes the MSE for b smaller than when using the direct calculation. For a I still get better results using the direct calculation, even when using Firth with intercept correction (logistf::flic()).

@Noah thanks. I have let this rest for a while because of the unbiased aspect of the estimators and also I was not able to wrap my head around any relevant theorems that might relate to efficiency. So I will have to look into the Firth correction. (at the same time I wonder about alternative examples with a similar dual approach in estimation). I guess that it should be possible to have MLE estimates based on the Gaussians that have lower variance than the estimates based on the logistic regression model, because the former have all the information...

... as in this question Sufficient Statistic and Maximum likelihood, at least I only need the sample means and sample variance as sufficient statistics. Then, even when the logistic regression gives a better estimate, I should be able to do the same with the sufficient statistics only.
